# Sort the results of a query using results of another query

Tags: php, mysql

Im working on a message board of some sort and i have everything up an running except one little part, the threads need to be sorted by the date/time of the latest post in them (standard forum format), which im having lots of trouble wrapping my head around.

This is the querys im using, i know its not pretty and its not safe, i will be reworking them once i learn how to do it properly.

```
$sql = "SELECT Thread_ID, Thread_Title, Board_ID, Author FROM threads WHERE Board_ID='$Board_ID' LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

$Thread_ID = $row['Thread_ID']; 
$Thread_Title = $row['Thread_Title'];   
$Board_ID = $row['Board_ID'];       
$Author = $row['Author']; 

$getauthor = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Member_ID='$Author'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getauthor))
{
$Post_Author = $row['Post_As']; }


$postcount = mysql_query("SELECT Post_ID FROM posts WHERE Thread_ID='$Thread_ID'");                 
$Posts = mysql_num_rows($postcount);

$getlatest = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE Thread_ID='$Thread_ID' ORDER by Post_DateTime DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getlatest))
{
$Post_DateTime = time_ago($row['Post_DateTime']);
$Member_ID = $row['Member_ID']; }

$getmember = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE Member_ID='$Member_ID'");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($getmember))
{
$Post_As = $row['Post_As']; }
```

So what im trying to do is Sort $sql by $getlatest, i tried adding another query above $sql that did basically the same as $getlatest and then had $sql order by that but alas it just broke everything.

I know i have to make a variable to sort the $sql by but its that variable thats driving me mad.

any help would be appreciated, thanks.

current error message as requested:

Fatal error: SQL - Unknown column 'posts2.LatestPost' in 'on clause' - SELECT threads.Thread_ID, threads.Thread_Title, threads.Board_ID, threads.Author, Sub1.LatestPost, Sub1.PostCount, members.Post_As, members2.Member_ID AS LastPostMemberID, members2.Post_As AS LastPostMemberPostAs FROM threads INNER JOIN (SELECT Thread_ID, MAX(posts.Post_DateTime) AS LatestPost, COUNT(*) AS PostCount FROM posts GROUP BY Thread_ID) Sub1 ON threads.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID INNER JOIN members ON threads.Author = members.Member_ID INNER JOIN posts posts2 ON posts2.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID AND posts2.LatestPost INNER JOIN members members2 ON members2.Member_ID = posts2.Member_ID WHERE threads.Board_ID='1' ORDER BY Sub1.LatestPost DESC LIMIT 0, 25 in C:\wamp\www\forum\include\threads.php on line 86

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it using something like this for your first query:-

```
$sql = "SELECT threads.Thread_ID, threads.Thread_Title, threads.Board_ID, threads.Author, MAX(posts.Post_DateTime) AS LatestPost
        FROM threads 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN posts ON threads.Thread_ID = posts.Thread_ID
        WHERE threads.Board_ID='$Board_ID' 
        GROUP BY SELECT threads.Thread_ID, threads.Thread_Title, threads.Board_ID, threads.Author
        ORDER BY LatestPost DESC
        LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
```

EDIT

Not tested the following but looking at your selects I think you could probably put it together into a single SELECT. Something like this:-

```
$sql = "SELECT threads.Thread_ID, threads.Thread_Title, threads.Board_ID, threads.Author, Sub1.LatestPost, Sub1.PostCount, members.Post_As, members2.Member_ID AS LastPostMemberID, members2.Post_As AS LastPostMemberPostAs
        FROM threads 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT Thread_ID, MAX(posts.Post_DateTime) AS LatestPost, COUNT(*) AS PostCount FROM posts GROUP BY Thread_ID) Sub1
        ON threads.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID
        INNER JOIN members 
        ON threads.Author = members.Member_ID
        INNER JOIN posts posts2
        ON posts2.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID AND posts2.Post_DateTime = Sub1.LatestPost
        INNER JOIN members members2
        ON members2.Member_ID = posts2.Member_ID
        WHERE threads.Board_ID='$Board_ID' 
        ORDER BY Sub1.LatestPost DESC
        LIMIT $offset, $rowsperpage";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    $Thread_ID = $row['Thread_ID']; 
    $Thread_Title = $row['Thread_Title'];   
    $Board_ID = $row['Board_ID'];       
    $Author = $row['Author']; 
    $Post_Author = $row['Post_As']; 
    $Posts = $row['PostCount']; 
    $Post_DateTime = time_ago($row['LatestPost']);
    $Member_ID = $row['LastPostMemberID']; 
    $Post_As = $row['LastPostMemberPostAs'];
```

Comment: this breaks the whole set of querys, i dont understand what half of that query is trying to do but it looks like its trying to sort by LatestPost which doesnt exist in either threads or posts table

Comment: It sorts by LatestPost, which is the maximum post date for each thread. Look at the MAX in the first line of the SELECT

Comment: this si the error its throwing back at me Fatal error: SQL in C:\wamp\www\forum\include\threads.php on line 86 line 86 is $result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

Comment: Change that line to _$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL - ".$sql, E_USER_ERROR);_ , and then post out the SELECT that has actually been used

Comment: by post out did you mean here? its a big error thats 188 characters too long for this little box but it basically says everything in $sql is broke, ill post a snip below

Comment: Fatal error: SQL - SELECT threads.Thread_ID, threads.Thread_Title, threads.Board_ID, threads.Author, Sub1.LatestPost, Sub1.PostCount, members.Post_As, members2.Member_ID AS LastPostMemberID, members2.Post_As AS LastPostMemberPostAs FROM threads INNER JOIN (SELECT Thread_ID, MAX(posts.Post_DateTime) AS LatestPost, COUNT(*) AS PostCount FROM posts GROUP BY Thread_ID) Sub1 ON threads.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID INNER JOIN members ON threads.Author = members.Member_ID INNER JOIN posts posts2 ON posts2.Thread_ID = Sub1.Thread_ID AND posts2.LatestPost INNER JOIN members members2 ON members2.Member...

Comment: Probably best to edit your original post to add that so I can see the bits that refer to the sort order, etc

Comment: The SQL looks OK, based on the limited info I have of your tables. Change line 86 to _$result = mysql_query($sql, $conn) or trigger_error("SQL - ".mysql_error()." - ".$sql, E_USER_ERROR);_ , this should put out the actual error.

Comment: Dude if i could, i would kiss you, thanks for putting up with me. works perfectly, thanks.

Comment: No problems. Putting out the sql error helps for debugging in future, but best to avoid it with live code (potentially gives a hacker extra info)